# Text not respecting \text within NewDocumentCommand within align*

Tags: align, xparse

Within an `align*` environment I have lines of the form

```latex
\Rightarrow &<\texttt{Program Code}, [a \mapsto 1, b \mapsto 2]> &\text{Rule Name}\\
\Rightarrow &<\texttt{Program Code 2}, [a \mapsto 2, b \mapsto 3]> &\text{Rule Name 2} \\
```

Giving

[image: LaTeX render of the above code]

I thought of making a macro to make this much easier, of the form

```latex
\pline{Program Code}{a \mapsto 2,b \mapsto 2}{Rule name}
```

I want the third argument, the rule name, to be optional. If so, it shouldn't show up on the line, on the right.

I was trying to use the native `ifx`/`else` combo but I switched to the `xparse` package. Right now, I have this:

```latex
\NewDocumentCommand{\pline}{+m +m o}{
    \Rightarrow &<\texttt{#1}, \ensuremath{[#2]}>
    \IfValueTF{#3}
        {&\text{#3}}
}
```

However, the rule names do not align right. See the below demonstration:

```latex
\begin{align*}
    % Explicit Code
    \Rightarrow &<\texttt{Program Code}, [a \mapsto 1, b \mapsto 2]> &\text{Rule Name} \\
    \Rightarrow &<\texttt{Program Code 2}, [a \mapsto 2, b \mapsto 3]> &\text{Rule Name 2} \\\\
    % Commands
    \pline{Program Code}{a \mapsto 1,b \mapsto 2}{Rule Name} \\
    \pline{Program Code 2}{a \mapsto 2,b \mapsto 3}{Rule Name 2}
\end{align*}
```

[image: Alignment fixed, but font wrong.]

To fix this, I put the `&` infront of `\IfValueTF` and removed it from before the `\text{#3}`. However, though this fixes the alignment issue, the font is still wrong and seems to stay in math mode, in spite of the `\text`.

How can I fix both these issues?

Minimal working example:

```latex
\documentclass[notitlepage]{report}

\usepackage{mathpazo}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{xparse}

\begin{document}

\NewDocumentCommand{\pline}{+m +m o}{
    \Rightarrow &<\texttt{#1}, \ensuremath{[#2]}>
    \IfValueTF{#3}
        {\&text{#3}}
}

\NewDocumentCommand{\plinealigned}{+m +m o}{
    \Rightarrow &<\texttt{#1}, \ensuremath{[#2]}>
    &\IfValueTF{#3}
        {\text{#3}}
}

\begin{align*}
    % Explicit Code
    \Rightarrow &<\texttt{Program Code}, [a \mapsto 1, b \mapsto 2]> &\text{Rule Name} \\
    \Rightarrow &<\texttt{Program Code 2}, [a \mapsto 2, b \mapsto 3]> &\text{Rule Name 2} \\\\
    % Commands
    \pline{Program Code}{a \mapsto 1,b \mapsto 2}{Rule Name} \\
    \pline{Program Code 2}{a \mapsto 2,b \mapsto 3}{Rule Name 2}\\\\
    % Commands with alignment fixed
    \plinealigned{Program Code}{a \mapsto 1,b \mapsto 2}{Rule Name} \\
    \plinealigned{Program Code 2}{a \mapsto 2,b \mapsto 3}{Rule Name 2}
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

[image: Image showing all three cases of the issue.]

Comment: You should change `\IfValueTF` to `\IfValueT` or add a pair of curly braces. `\IfValueTF` takes three arguments: one for the thing to be tested, one for the true branch and one for the false branch. But in your defintion, you miss the latter. Actually, with `O{}` instead of `o`, you can omit the test altogether.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need `\IfValueT` not `\IfValueTF`. You misplaced `&`, `{&\text{#3}}` not `{\&text{#3}}` in `\pline`. The `o` is optional argument, you need `[]` not `{}`.

```latex
\documentclass[notitlepage]{report}

\usepackage{mathpazo}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{xparse}

\begin{document}

\NewDocumentCommand{\pline}{+m +m o}{
    \Rightarrow &<\texttt{#1}, \ensuremath{[#2]}>
    \IfValueT{#3}
        {&\text{#3}}
}

\NewDocumentCommand{\plinealigned}{+m +m o}{
    \Rightarrow &<\texttt{#1}, \ensuremath{[#2]}>
    &\IfValueT{#3}
        {\text{#3}}
}

\begin{align*}
    % Explicit Code
    \Rightarrow &<\texttt{Program Code}, [a \mapsto 1, b \mapsto 2]> &\text{Rule Name} \\
    \Rightarrow &<\texttt{Program Code 2}, [a \mapsto 2, b \mapsto 3]> &\text{Rule Name 2} \\\\
    % Commands
    \pline{Program Code}{a \mapsto 1,b \mapsto 2}[Rule Name] \\
    \pline{Program Code 2}{a \mapsto 2,b \mapsto 3}[Rule Name 2]\\
    % Commands with alignment fixed
    \plinealigned{Program Code}{a \mapsto 1,b \mapsto 2}[Rule Name] \\
    \plinealigned{Program Code 2}{a \mapsto 2,b \mapsto 3}[Rule Name 2]
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Oh, I believe the `\&text` was just a mistake by me in copying the command over, but the answer does work, thank you.

Comment: @Harith note you only need `xparse` in old latex releases. `\NewDocumentCommand` is defined in current formats with no package needed.

Answer (score 5):

There are a few errors in your code:

1. `\&text` should be `&\text`
2. `\ensuremath` does nothing useful
3. the argument type should be `m`, not `+m`
4. `<` and `>` aren't to be used as brackets
5. an optional argument is inside square brackets, not braces

I add some space after the `\Rightarrow` and use `\langle` and `\rangle` for the angle brackets. Note the different spacing. Also `&&\text{}` for better alignment.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}

\begin{document}

\NewDocumentCommand{\pline}{m m o}{%
  \Rightarrow{} & \langle\texttt{#1}, [#2]\rangle
  \IfValueT{#3}{&&\text{#3}}%
}

\begin{align*}
\pline{Program Code}{a \mapsto 1,b \mapsto 2}[Rule Name] \\
\pline{Program Code 2}{a \mapsto 2,b \mapsto 3}[Rule Name 2]
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Why is `\ensuremath` doing nothing useful? The command `\pline` (as written) *must* be used in math mode, because of `\Rightarrow`.

If you really want `<` and `>`, make them into the proper kind of math atoms.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}

\begin{document}

\NewDocumentCommand{\pline}{m m o}{%
  \Rightarrow{} & \mathopen<\texttt{#1}, [#2]\mathclose>
  \IfValueT{#3}{&&\text{#3}}%
}

\begin{align*}
\pline{Program Code}{a \mapsto 1,b \mapsto 2}[Rule Name] \\
\pline{Program Code 2}{a \mapsto 2,b \mapsto 3}[Rule Name 2]
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

[image]